# Core 3 : No code generator found with the name 'identity'

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

dotnet --info

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):

Version:   3.0.100

Commit:    04339c3a26 
Runtime Environment:

OS Name:     Mac OS X

OS Version:  10.15

OS Platform: Darwin

RID:         osx.10.15-x64

Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/ 
Host (useful for support):

Version: 3.0.0

Commit:  7d57652f33 
.NET Core SDKs installed:

3.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk] 
.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

​

I created a new ASP.Net Core  MVC web app and added packages:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```

I try to run the command:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h
```

and I get:

```
Selected Code Generator: identity
No code generator found with the name 'identity'.
```

**​Why isn't 'identity' a valid code generator since updating the SDK and runtime?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `dotnet add package` command line,it would generate the following reference in .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Change the Version to 3.0.0 like below:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
```

Comment: thanks so much. I didn't notice the version on installs. So you'd think the add package process would verify matching versions... sheesh

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message with scaffolding identity pages in .Net 6.

> No code generator found with the name 'identity'.

Reinstalling packages did not help.

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity
```

resulted in an error

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.

So installed the code generator manually (elevated!):

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

After that I tried scaffolding in Visual Studio again. Same error. Then I tried with dotnet:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity
```

Which now worked.

Oh, and I had a Pre-build event configured, that caused problems during scaffolding. Removing the pre-build event for scaffolding and re-adding it after worked.